# How can I change an object if it is in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

I have an ArrayList of Dogs.  If Fluffy is in the ArrayList, I want to change its name to Fido.  If it is not in the ArrayList, I want to add it, and then change its name to Fido.

So I can check if Fido exists in the ArrayList, but how can i retrieve it so that I can make changes?  The following is the closest I have come.  I am looking for something along the lines of `dogs.getElementEqualTo(new Dog("Fido"));`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Dog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        dogs.add(new Dog("Fido"));
        Dog dog = new Dog("Fido");
        if (dogs.contains(dog)) {
            dog.name = "Fluffy";
        }
        System.out.println(dogs.get(0).name); //prints Fido
    }

    String name;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Dog)) return false;

        Dog dog = (Dog) o;

        return !(name != null ? !name.equals(dog.name) : dog.name != null);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I tried changing my main method to this, but it did not work:

```
ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
dogs.add(new Dog("Fido"));
Dog dog = new Dog("Fido");
if (dogs.contains(dog)) {
    dogs.get(dogs.indexOf(dog)).name = "Fluffy";
}
System.out.println(dogs.get(0).name);
```

Comment: What does that code do? Show the output.

Comment: Just loop the elements and check each one (or just until the first one).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis darn.  Will do. I was hoping there was a prettier way, but that will work. Thanks!

Comment: You can keep the elements in a parallel map with whatever lookup you need (eg. by name).

Comment: every collection provides a method `contains` and lists provide furthermore `indexOf` for objects that overload `equals`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the (first) index of Fido using:

```
int indexOfFido = dogs.indexOf(new Dog("Fido"));
```

and then retrieve the element using:

```
dogs.get(indexOfFido);
```

However, depending upon the concrete implementation of `List` that you are using, it may be more efficient to iterate through the list:

```
Dog fido = new Dog("Fido");
for (Dog dog : dogs) {
  if (fido.equals(dog)) {  // Do the comparison this way round, since
                           // elements of list can be null in general.
    // Do whatever.
    break;  // Unless you want to do the same to all instances of Fido.
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the main method to this, and it did not work:

        ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        dogs.add(new Dog("Fido"));
        Dog dog = new Dog("Fido");
        if (dogs.contains(dog)) {
            dogs.get(dogs.indexOf(dog)).name = "Fluffy";
        }
        System.out.println(dogs.get(0).name);

Comment: Also, you don't need to call `contains` and `indexOf` separately - `indexOf` returns -1 if the element is not found. You're basically scanning the list twice.

Comment: It was auto-generated by my IDE

Comment: It prints "Fluffy" for me.

Comment: That was strange...i redid the build and it worked.  I think IntelliJ may have glitched on me.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean found = false;
for(Dog a : dogs) {
    if(a.name.equals("Fluffy") {
        a.name = "Fido";
        found = true;
}

if(!found) {
    dogs.add(new Dog("Fido"));
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how your Dog object works internally, my answer is based off the idea that the Dog class is something like this:

```
public static String name;
public Dog(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if (dogs.contains(dog))` is evaluating true as you would want, but you are modifying the local variable `dog` and not the `Dog` object inside your `ArrayList`

Change

```
dog.name = "Fluffy";
```

To

```
dogs.get(dogs.indexOf(dog)).name = "Fluffy";
```

And you'll get your desired results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
    dogs.add(new Dog("Fido"));
    Dog dog = new Dog("Fido");
    if (dogs.contains(dog)) {
        dogs.get(dogs.indexOf(dog)).name = "Fluffy";
    } else {
        dogs.add(dog);
    }

    System.out.println(dogs.get(0).name); //prints Fido
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you can use `filter` on the `List` stream, and then `findAny` and finally `ifPresent` in sequence.

Here's a quick example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<>();
    things.add(new Thing("thing one"));
    things.add(new Thing("thing two"));
    System.out.println(things);
    things.stream().filter(t -> t.toString()
            .contains("one"))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(t -> t.setName("three"));
    System.out.println(things);
}

public static class Thing{
    private String name;
    public Thing(String s){name=s;}
    public String toString(){return "Thing{name="+name+"}";}
    public void setName(String s){ name = s;}
    public int hashcode(){return name.hashCode();}
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return o != null && this.toString().equals(o.toString());
    }
}
```

And the output

```
[Thing{name=thing one}, Thing{name=thing two}]
[Thing{name=three}, Thing{name=thing two}]
```

Notice that the first element has been changed.